# Dugundji topology textbook. Is this an error?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

> 3.4. **Theorem**
>   Let $W$ be well-ordered, and $\Sigma\subset I(W)$ any family with the following properties:
>   (a) Each union of members of $\Sigma$ belongs to $\Sigma$.
>   (b) If $W(a)\in\Sigma$, then also $W(a)\cup \{a\}\in\Sigma$.
>   Then $\Sigma = I(W)$ and, in particular, $W\in\Sigma$.

$I(W)$ denotes the set of all ideals of $W$.

But isn't the following a counterexample to this Theorem?  Consider $W = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $\Sigma=\{\{1,2,3,4\},\{1,2,3,4,5\}\}$. These meet the conditions (a), (b), correct?

But $\Sigma\neq I(W).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $\Sigma$ does not satisfy condition (a): if you take the subset $\emptyset\subset\Sigma$, then the union $\bigcup\emptyset=\emptyset$ is not an element of $\Sigma$.  That is, the union of elements of $\Sigma$ consisting of no elements at all is not in $\Sigma$.

Comment: Aren't the members of $\Sigma$ only $\{1,2,3,4\},\{1,2,3,4,5\}$? Is $\emptyset$ also a member?

Comment: $\emptyset$ is a subset of $\Sigma$, not an element.  Condition (a) means that if $A\subseteq\Sigma$ is any subset, then the union of all the elements of $A$ is an element of $\Sigma$.  Here I'm taking $A=\emptyset$.

Comment: the term 'member' means subset? I thought member = element. Otherwise, member = element, and 'nothing' also is member in this context?

Comment: @Arbitrary When one says "union of members", you need some way of indexing the members you're taking the union over; that is, you need to pick a subset of $\tau \subset \Sigma$, and then write $\cup_{x \in \tau} x$. We are simply taking the empty union, indexed by the empty set.

Comment: The thing is, you can't talk about nothing. You can talk about **the set which has no members/elements**, but that is not nothing: it is a set, and it can be a member, or not be a member, of some other set.

Comment: Ok I understood completely. Thank you all.